# How is memory allocated in constructor released when the constructor throws an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, constructor

Below is my sample code. Base class has a pointer of A class with memory assigned from heap using new operator. I am explicitly throwing an exception. Since I am not invoking delete on *ptr the memory allocated by new is not released. Since the object is not constructed completely how can we release memory?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class A
{
    public:
    A()
    {
        cout<<"A::ctor"<<endl;
    }
    ~A()
    {
        cout<<"A::Dctor"<<endl;
    }
};
class Base
{
    public:
    A *ptr;
    Base()
    {
       ptr = new A();
        cout<<"Base::Ctor"<<endl;
        throw std::exception();
    }
    ~Base()
    {
        delete ptr;
        cout<<"Base::Dtor"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try{
        Base bobj;

    }
    catch(exception e)
    {

        cout<<e.what();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When Base constructor throws exception the control goes to catch block and exception is handled. But how is the memory allocated by `ptr = new A();` released?

Now I know using smart pointers would solve the issue. But before C++11 how were such situations handled.

In addition, I would like to know how do we close file handlers of a file handler is opened in constructor and constructor has an exception?

```
Base()
{
 ofstream myfile;
 myfile.open("myfile.txt");
 ..........
 throw std::exception();
}

~Base()
{
  myfile.close();
}
```

Comment: "I would like to know how do we close file handlers of a file handler is opened in constructor and constructor has an exception?" `try { ... } catch() { myfile.close(); throw; }`

Answer (score 5):

The memory associated with `ptr` is never released!

Yes, that was always a problem.

Prior to C++11 you could build your own smart pointer class (or use the one in Boost for example), or take care to `delete` prior to throwing an exception. Putting `ptr` in a base class is also an alternative: the base class constructor will complete before the derived constructor's function body is reached.

Comment: So you mean to say prior to C++11 such kind of memory leaks were never resolved? We don't have inheritance here.

Comment: @arjunjawalkar: Well they were using the techniques I mention in the final paragraph.

Comment: as you said "delete prior to throwing an exception", say we are not explicitly throwing an exception but due to some reason an exception occurred which is general in programming, we could not determine where to delete the allocated memory.

Comment: @arjunjawalkar: Then using smart pointers is an obvious fix. E.g. `std::auto_ptr` (now removed in C++17 following its deprecation in C++11), although it had strange copy semantics.

Comment: @arjunjawalkar you may wanna have a look [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). Smart pointers (and RAII in general) have been the standard technique to deal with resource management in C++ for decades now. C++11 didn't introduce these ideas, it just gave us tools to make them even better…